# Print lines between line numbers from a line list and save every instance in separate file using GNU Parallel

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, gnu-parallel

I have a file, say "Line_File" with a list of line start & end numbers and file ID :

```
F_a 1 108
F_b 109 1210
F_c 131 1190
```

I have another file, "Data_File" from where I need to fetch all the lines between the line numbers fetched from the Line_File.

The command in sed:

```
'sed -n '1,108p' Data_File > F_a.txt
```

does the job but I need to do this for all the values in columns 2 & 3 of Line_File and save it with the file name mentioned in the column 1 of the Line_File.

If $1, $2 and $3 are the three cols of Line_File then I am looking for a command something like

```
'sed -n '$2,$3p' Data_File > $1.txt
```

I can run the same using Bash Loop but that will be very slow for a very large file, say 40GB.

I specifically want to do this because I am trying to use GNU Parallel to make it faster and line number based slicing will make the output non-overlapping. I am trying to execute command like this

```
cat Data_File | parallel -j24 --pipe --block 1000M --cat LC_ALL=C sed -n '$2,$3p' > $1.txt
```

But I am no able to actually use the column assignment $1,$2 and $3 properly.

I tried the following command:

```
awk '{system("sed -n \""$2","$3"p\" Data_File > $1"NR)}' Line_File
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea where I am going wrong?

P.S If my question is not clear then please point out what else I should be sharing.

Comment: How many lines are Data_File and Line_File?

Comment: Data_File is huge, 62GB
Line_File has 132433 entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `xargs` with `-P` (parallel) option:

```
xargs -P 8 -L 1 bash -c 'sed -n "$2,$3p" Data_File > $1.txt' _ < Line_File
```

**Explanation:**

- This `xargs` command takes `Line_File` as input by using `<`
- `-P 8` option allows it to run up to 8 processes in parallel
- `-L 1` makes `xargs` process one line at a time
- `bash -c ...` forks `bash` for each line in input file
- `_` before `<` passes `_` as `$0` and passes remaining 3 column in each input line as `$1, $2,`$3`
- `sed -n` runs `sed` command for each line by forming a command line

Or you may use `gnu parallel` like this:

```
parallel --colsep '[[:blank:]]' "sed -n '{2},{3}p' Data_File > {1}.txt" :::: Line_File
```

[Check parallel examples from official doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#A-single-input-source)

Comment: I tried this command but I get the following error 

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'

Comment: True. I have often experienced such problems using bash, sed and awk commands. Something to do with shell environment I am having, which I don't know. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: I get the same error, with additional lines like this

    `sed -n ',p' Data_File > F_a\ \ 38800\ \ \ \ \ 38892.txt`

Comment: It is TAB Delimited and I had already made the necessary changes, I am using

`-t --colsep '\t' ` in my command.

For some reason the `{2} {3}` are not giving the values to the sed.

Comment: Yes ... the output does have DOS line endings and it is tab delimited
The output is:

`F_c  698  3809$`

Comment: 1. The output of cat -A Line_File is `F_a 1 108$` and not as you mentioned.

2. Ran the command and still getting the same error 

`sed -n ''',108p' Data_File > F_a.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198676/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ashutosh).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

this scans the data file only once

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {k=$1; s[k]=$2; e[k]=$3; next} 
               {for(k in s) if(FNR>=s[k] && FNR<=e[k]) print > (k".txt")}' lines data
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and sed):

```
parallel --dry-run -a lineFile -C' ' "sed -n '{2},{3}p' dataFile > {1}'
```

This uses the column separator `-C ' '` and sets it to a space, this then sets the first 3 fields of the lineFile to `{1}`,`{2}` and `{3}`. The `--dry-run` option allows you to check the commands parallel generates before running for real. Once the commands look correct remove the `--dry-run` option.

Comment: I have already tried this command but the problem is somehow it fails to fetch values of {2} and {3}. I get following output

`sed -n ''',1405p' Data_File > ZC66326976`
`sed -n ''',1491p' Data_File > ZC66360935`
`sed -n ''',1594p' Data_File > ZC66377449`
`
ZC* is the file header in real

Comment: @Ashutosh it could be that the line file is tab separated or some combinations of spaces and or tabs. The `-C` option takes a regexp so change it from `-C ' ' ` to `-C '\s+'` or to see which column is which change the command to echo and check i.e. `echo {1} {2} {3} instead of the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not to be CPU constrained. It is more likely your disks will be the limiting factor. To avoid reading DataFile over and over again, you should run as many jobs as possible in parallel. That way caching will help you:

```
cat Line_file |
  parallel -j0 --colsep ' ' sed -n {2},{3}p Data_File \> {1}.txt
```

Comment: That's true but as mentioned above,
I have already tried this command but the problem is somehow it fails to fetch values of {2} and {3}. I get following output

`sed -n ''',1405p' Data_File > ZC66326976`
`sed -n ''',1491p' Data_File > ZC66360935`
`sed -n ''',1594p' Data_File > ZC66377449`
`
ZC* is the file header in real